# cakephp 3 auth not working

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, model-view-controller

i try to use Auth in cakephp3 but i got return error

i am sure that data correct

For note password field size is 255 char

sql log return only user_mail filed where

```
  phi_members.user_mail = 'gathuth@gmail.com'
```

why it not include user_password !! 
and row result is 1

PhimembersController.php

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

Class PhimembersController  extends AppController {

    var $name="Phi_members";

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');


    public function index()
    {
echo'Hello World';
    }
    public function show() {




        $this->set('phi_members',$this->Phi_members->find('all'));




    }

public function initialize()
{   

    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'loginRedirect' => [
                'action' => 'index'] , 'loginAction' => [
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'phi_members',
                'fields' => ['username' => 'user_mail','password' => 'user_password']
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}


public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'login']);
    }




        public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }











}








?>
```

login.ctp

```
<h1><?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?></h1>
<?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username and password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('user_mail') ?>
                <?= $this->Form->input('user_password') ?>

    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Any Help